# sendRedirect after time interval avoiding javascript or php

Tags: jsp, redirect, httpresponse

How can I do the following

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

after a certain time interval from another jsp without using javascript or php?

The idea is to show an error in a "error_page.jsp" and then after some time automatically redirect the user to the index page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Refresh HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) is supposed to control timed redirects.

You can set it in HTML, by adding to your `error_page.jsp` this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=next_page.jsp">
```

(5 stands for 5 seconds before `next_page.jsp` gets loaded)

You would most probably pass the name of the next page as a parameter to the JSP, or a request attribute, so that instead of `next_page.jsp` it would be `${param.nextPage}` or just `${nextPage}` respectively.

And of course you can set the same header from servlet: `response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=next_page.jsp");`.

You could even put this code inside JSP `<% response.setHeader("Refresh", "5;url=next_page.jsp"); %>`.

Comment: I was looking for a solution included in the servlet even if this is the most simple and I think more efficient solution.
Thanks